# How to close an HTTP request in Node.js and prevent further data from being sent?

Tags: node.js, http, security, file-upload, stream

I'm building a file upload handling library in Node.js. I'm talking about raw `http.IncomingMessage`-type requests, I'm not using Express.

Let's say the library consists of a `Transform` stream, which limits incoming request size. I'm trying to handle a potential threat: a malicious client sends an infinitely long request to my server.

What to do once the request stream size exceeded the limit? I want to know how to close the request so that no further data can be sent over the wire and waste the server resources (which opens a possibility to exhaust server resources and practically DDoS it).

1. Is calling `response.end()` enough to close the request, the underlying connection, and prevent from further data from being sent over the wire?
2. If not, should I call `request.destroy()`?
3. Should I `request.unpipe(MyLengthLimiterTransformStream)` before calling destroying the request?

Digging around the internet and source code of libraries concerned with file uploads, I've spotted several solutions to this, but they all seem to be not very secure.

1. Unpiping the request from any `Transform`s/`Writeable`s and calling `request.resume()`. As far as I understand this still keeps the server (marginally) busy, keeps the connection open and allows the client to send infinite amounts of data to the server.
2. Same but with `request.pause()`. With well-behaved clients I assume first Node.js's stream buffers will be filled, and the client will be signalled (via TCP?) to stop sending data. But what if the client is malicious and doesn't answer to the demand, and keeps sending data?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to cancel all behaviors and close the connection, `response.end()` would not enough to handle those.

since node.js is made to process asyncronous tasks, even if you call `response.end()`, node.js would be still on processing in microtask queue and not disconnection until the process is done.

***How to resolve?***

if you want to cancel tasks and close the connection, you must use promise object which is stable to handle asyncronous tasks. or async, await,..etc.

you can code validity check a incomming data before start processing in promise object, And handle the connection.

You can use `request.destroy()` to disconnect, but you should handle this with caution. It would abort requests unexpectly and lead client-side errors. and also using `process.exit()` to abort tasks is not recommended to cancel tasks for the same reason.